# Reference outputs from another local project in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Consider the following directory structure

- project_resources

  - dns

    - main.tf
  - compute

    - main.tf
- development

  - main.tf
- production

  - main.tf
- global

  - main.tf

In my TF, I have a global module, which should only be run once. i.e. set up DNS with ACM etc.

Once the global module is setup, I may apply development or production. However, for both production and development, i need to set a record in my DNS - hence I need to be able to access the id of the DNS zone from the global module.

For the global env I obviously export the output from my DNS zone, e.g.:

```
output "route53_zone_id" {
    value = aws_route53_zone.proj_hosted_zone.id
}
```

Since I'm treating global, production and dev as separate "projects", I cannot reference `route53_zone_id` from a module import, so I did something along the lines of this (inspired by another SO post):

```
data "global_state" "global" {

  backend = "local"
  config = {
    path = "../global/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

locals {
    dns_servers = data.global_state.global.outputs.route53_zone_id
}
```

but once I run `terraform init`, it seems as if terraform thinks that the global data object is a provider, since I get the following error:

> Error: Failed to query available provider packages. Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/global: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/global

I'm therefore keen to understand, what I am missing in terms of getting the output variables from the global project in respectively development and production environments.

Comment: I think you want data source named `terraform_remote_state` and not `global_state` as such thing does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work but with the [`terraform_remote_state` data source](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/remote-state-data#example-usage-local-backend):

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "global" {
  backend = "local"

  config = {
    path = "../global/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```